# Symfony Doctrine issue with entities

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony5

I been provided with database with relations:

tables:

department

- id
- name
- locationId

location

- id
- name

personel

- id
- firstName
- lastName
- jobTitle
- email
- departmentId

While I create Entity and Migration its create for me:
for p.:

- name, department_id_id, first_name, last_name, job_title, email
  for d.:
- id, location_id_id, name
  for l:
- id, name

How can I "force" it while creating entity to use field names as provided above?

Answer (score -1):

It's simple. Add a `column` value in the annotation, I'm assuming that you are using annotations, but with YML or XML is petty munch the same.

```
/** @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="location_id_id") */
private $locationId;
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column

It applies for relations as well.

Comment: do you have any idea about orm config naming_strategy to set names as variables in entity?